# CSS Grid and Absolute Positioning on Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari, css-grid

I have a problem with a css grid layout.

The grid container is absolutely positioned and the grid-template-rows contains an 1fr to allow one row to take all the free space.

This displays correctly on all current browsers except the latest Safari installed with macOS 10.13.2

The issue seems to be caused by it not calculating the freespace if the height is not explicitly set.

Am I missing something or is there a workaround?

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/w5xho67w/49/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 150px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 150px;
  grid-template-areas: "a b" "c d";
}

.wrapper>div {
  outline: solid 1px #aaa;
  padding: 10px;
}

.game {
  grid-area: a;
}

.player {
  grid-area: b;
}

.rules {
  grid-area: d;
}

.controls {
  grid-area: c;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="game">game</div>
  <div class="player">player</div>
  <div class="rules">rules</div>
  <div class="controls">controls</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2017 `top: 0; bottom 0` is more like a dirty hack. Just give the `.wrapper` a minimum height as 100% of the viewport - 100vh.

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: In the actual implementation the reason the wrapper is absolutely positioned is because its placement is offset in its parent so top, bottom,left,right will have none zero values and 100% or 100vh wont be appropriate.

Comment: Is the offset to its parent static or otherwise calculable? Else `height: calc(100% - the_offset)` might fix it.

Comment: Yeah I had also found after posting that setting the height to a css calc value would appear to fix the problem.